# Insert query inside if ele if statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried inserting an array into the database. It does inserts but only with the admin = 0 && special admin != 1. When I try altering the database in which i will set admin to 3 and special admin to != 1 it does not insert at all.

Needed help here so here's the code I have so far

```
$ques = "SELECT * FROM ip_restriction where ipnum = '".$ip_2."'";
$ress = mysql_query($ques);
if ($roww = mysql_fetch_array($ress)) {
  if ($row ['admin'] == 0 && $row['special_admin']!=1) 
  {
    $queinsert = "INSERT INTO tblid (ipadd, ipdept, createdby, datecreated)
                  VALUES ('".$ip_2."', 'AGENT', 'Admin', NOW())";
  }
  elseif ($row ['admin'] == 0 && $row['special_admin']==1 ) 
  {
    $queinsert = "INSERT INTO tblid (ipadd, ipdept, createdby, datecreated)
          VALUES ('".$ip_2."', 'AGENT', 'Admin', NOW())";
  }
   elseif ($row ['admin'] == 3 && $row['special_admin']!=1 ) 
  {
    $queinsert = "INSERT INTO tblid (ipadd, ipdept, createdby, datecreated)
          VALUES ('".$ip_2."', 'CLIENT', 'Admin', NOW())";
  }
   elseif ($row ['admin'] == 3 && $row['special_admin']==1 ) 
  {
    $queinsert = "INSERT INTO tblid (ipadd, ipdept, createdby, datecreated)
          VALUES ('".$ip_2."', 'CLIENT', 'Admin', NOW())";
  }
   elseif ($row ['admin'] == 4   && $row['special_admin']!=1 ) 
  {
    $queinsert = "INSERT INTO tblid (ipadd, ipdept, createdby, datecreated)
          VALUES ('".$ip_2."', 'AGENT', 'Admin', NOW())";

  }
    $ressinput= mysql_query($queinsert);
  header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: Where/how does `$roww` get into the picture; typo, right?

Comment: I'd have to say it looks like you could reduce this code because most/all of the statements are the same

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Kind of saw an alternative method to solve this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually try this. bcoz whatever the condition is you are inserting the same values in the DB. So I don't understand the actual meaning of putting the conditions.

```
$ques = "SELECT * FROM ip_restriction where ipnum = '".$ip_2."'";
$ress = mysql_query($ques);
if ($roww = mysql_fetch_array($ress)) 
{
    $queinsert = "INSERT INTO tblid (ipadd, ipdept, createdby, datecreated)
                             VALUES ('".$ip_2."', 'AGENT', 'Admin', NOW())";
}
$ressinput= mysql_query($queinsert);
header('Location: index.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ressinput = mysql_query($queinsert);

if (!$ressinput) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```